# Domain layer and the persistence layer difference

Tags: java, persistence

Does the domain layer and the persistence layer refer to same or are they different. 
Domain layer is the DAO's which we usually map to database tables right? so does persistence layer means the same or is there more?

And if we are calling the POJO's which map to database tables as DAO's, what we say the classes which resides the execution of queries and populate those DAO's (POJOS).

What is the best practice? Keeping the query execution code inside those POJO's or make them a separate class? i mean example suppose A is the class map to database table A. Do we need to implement separate class like ADaoImpl for place the query related code need for class A? i belive its not right? isnt it the best practice keep all the DAO objects populating, query executions etc related to all DAO classes in a single class called something RDBMSDaoImpl. so we called that class a DAO Implementation class of out application which belongs to the DAO layer right?

So as a summary the POJOS(DAO) and DAOImpl is the DAO layer of our application right? and the persistence layer is..?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia: "A business logic layer (BLL), also known as the domain layer". So that's you service layer, where you perform your business logic. The persistence layer is responsible for manipulating the database, and it is used by the service layer.

(Btw, I would prefer "service layer" instead of "domain layer" in an anemic application - that is, an application with stateless, fat services and domain objects with only getters and setters.)

Comment: yes, I'd say so. Though it can theoretically be two separate layers, I guess

Comment: Wkikipedia: "Within a BLL objects can further be partitioned into business processes (business activities) and business entities. Business process objects typically implement the controller pattern, i.e. they contain no data elements but have methods that orchestrate interaction among business entities. Business entities typically correspond to entities in the logical domain model, rather than the physical database model". I think the business entities they talking should be domain model and business processes should be service layer. isnt it?

Answer (score 2):

The domain layer is where you model your objects and application features. If you are building an Invoicing application the domain layer should contain the Invoice, Vat and InvoiceItem objects for example. The DAO layer is responsible for retrieving and saving objects from your storage (RDMS database, NoSQL database, etc).
In your code, you could have something like

```java
public InvoiceDao {
    public void insert(Invoice invoice) {
    //use your database api to insert invoice
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. so what you mean is domain layer and DAO layer is diferent know? sounds right? btw i have edit my question by adding more. do u have a asnswer for my extended question

Comment: you should keep the class containing data and business logic separate from the class that persists the objects. Pojos are not DAO. If youllok at the sample code I provided it should be clear that Pojos and DAO are tow different set of classes with very different tasks. the DAO layer is responsible for managing the persistent state of POJO. The Domain (or Service) layer is where to put the business logic

Comment: yes thanks. but i should add its the service layer which implement the business logic and keep the domain object as pojos without any business implementaion right? So its basically the flow is view <-> controller <-> service layer (business logic) <-> DAO layer <-> Domain layer right?

Comment: the response is more complicated, it really depends how do you want to structure you application. the chain <-> controller <-> service layer (business logic) <-> DAO layer  is a common one. Domain layer object are used inside business logic and within the dao layer to enable persistence. if you model you domain objects as simple pojo you can use then ad DTO in the view/controller layer.

Comment: u mean if i model the domain objects as pojo, the term DTO's refer to same right?

Answer (score 1):

1- persistence layer : is the layer that deal with the database,
  it consist of a set of classes that maps the database and all operation on that 
  table.
 summery: you separate database from business layer.
2- business(DAL) : initiate (create) objects form classes that existing in persistence layer.